# Is burn-in on my LCD panel normal?

Tags: lcd, burn-in

The other day I bought a new computer monitor (Acer G246HYLbd, LED backlight, IPS panel, 24").

Apart from the fact that it doesn't feel like a "real" IPS panel (at certain angles part of the screen is dimmer), the screen somehow has a weird burn-in issue. After about 15-20 minutes of viewing a static image (like a PDF for example) and then switching to a dark image, I can already read bigger text on the area where the PDF was. In fact, while I was writing this I can already see the outline of this text box if I switch to a dark window (which is 100% opaque).

On my old monitor I never had anything like this. I also tested the same scenario on it with zero burn-in.

Is burn-in still a thing with modern LCD panels or is it just that I bought a really cheap monitor?

EDIT: I was on YouTube few minutes ago for maybe 15 minutes and I was able to take a picture of the burn-in afterwards. If you know the YouTube logo, you will easily recognize it and this was just a short time I had it on the screen while watching a video.

[image: Photo of burn-in marks]

Comment: Its not a normal thing, especially on a new monitor. I'd suggest documenting it, and contacting the support line for acer. Sounds like bad QC and you got a lemon

Comment: @JourneymanGeek so you would say that it can happen during production that one monitor has this issue and it is not a design flaw of the whole model?

Comment: That sounds like something that really ought not to be a feature. Its definately a fault, and you should contact acer to check.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Okay, thanks for your comment! I will contact them and see what their opinion is and hopefully I will get a replacement soon.

Comment: This is an old question, but IPS panels are more susceptible to ghosting than other LCD panels.  So yes, this is normal.  It's temporary and if it doesn't disappear quickly, you can clear it by displaying a solid white screen for awhile, or run one of the YouTube video patterns that clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes burn-in is still a thing for LCD panels. Sometimes flashing black and white fixes it, if it is a temporary burn-in. Permanent burn-in is very rare these days. Since 2010 I think I have saw only one case of permanent LCD burn-in.

If it is a permanent burn-in you most likely have a faulty panel, you should consider sending it for a RMA.

Comment: But it can't be normal that viewing a static image for maybe 10 minutes already leaves a burn-in mark. I have never seen that on any monitor, not even the old CRT screens.

Comment: @comfreak no its not normal at all. As JourneymanGeek said there must have been a bad quality check from Acer. LCD burn-ins are very rare these days.

Comment: Yes I agree, but since you wrote in your answer that it is still a thing, it made the impression that my issue is normal. I don't have a permanent burn-in but after 10 minutes or so I already see effects of a temporary one which is not even okay for a CRT in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Burn-in is permanent. If it dissipates after, for example, panel is turned off for same period it was on, then what you deal with is image retention or image persistence.

As JourneymanGeek and Ayan both state, burn in is very rare nowadays. But image retention is not. In fact it is inevitable given the way modern LCDs work.
That being said, image retention should not be a thing after 10-15 mins. Should be more like several hours.

Give it a few days to stabilise. It is a new monitor, it can happen and it should go away on it's own. If not, try changing (lower or increase) refresh rate and/or brightness, If that doesn't work use LCD conditioning function in the menu (or equivalent). If that doesn't help either, try changing cables. If possible try other connection type. i.e. change from HDMI to DP.

Only after all changes fail, contact support. Because this means that monitor's mainboard may be faulty.